# FILTER function is working but when [include] input cell empty, function is still spilling randomly

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have seriously searched and searched to understand why this started to happen when it wasn't happening prior. Please could someone assist if you have come across this yourself?

Sincerely!
Mark

Comment: Without seeing your formula - how should we help you?

Comment: the result is ok - it returns all rows where colum G is empty - and there are a lot of them. Look into row 26: column G is empty but there are values in colum H and I --> that is what is returned